# How to query the top TWO and the bottom TWO values at the same time in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am able to query the MAX and MIN at the same time but in my case I need the first TWO max and the first TWO min. I am able to query the top two and the bottom two but separately. Like this

```
SELECT playerName,teamName, scoreChange,category 
FROM players order by scoreChange desc limit 0,2
```

and

```
SELECT playerName,teamName, scoreChange,category 
FROM players order by scoreChange limit 0,2
```

the following query is working fine but it results only in max and min values .

```
SELECT playerName,teamName, scoreChange,category
FROM players
WHERE scoreChange = (SELECT MAX(scoreChange) FROM players)
UNION
SELECT playerName,teamName, scoreChange,category
FROM players
WHERE scoreChange = (SELECT MIN(scoreChange) FROM players)
```

Comment: `UNION` plus [_groupwise-max twice_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please edit your answer as

```
SELECT playerName,teamName, scoreChange,category
FROM player WHERE scoreChange = (SELECT MAX(scoreChange) FROM players)

          UNION

SELECT playerName,teamName, scoreChange,category
FROM players WHERE scoreChange =  (SELECT MAX(scoreChange) FROM players
WHERE scoreChange < (SELECT MAX(scoreChange) FROM players))

          UNION

 SELECT playerName,teamName, scoreChange,category
 FROM players
 WHERE scoreChange =  (SELECT MIN(scoreChange) FROM players)

          UNION

 SELECT playerName,teamName, scoreChange,category
 FROM players WHERE scoreChange =  (SELECT MIN(scoreChange) FROM players 
 WHERE scoreChange > (SELECT MIN(scoreChange) FROM players))
```

You may also try this one

```
 SELECT playerName,teamName, scoreChange,category
 FROM players JOIN 
 (SELECT DISTINCT scoreChange FROM players ORDER BY scoreChange DESC
 LIMIT 2) a ON players.scoreChange=a.scoreChange

                      UNION

 SELECT playerName,teamName, scoreChange,category
 FROM players JOIN 
 (SELECT DISTINCT scoreChange FROM players ORDER BY scoreChange LIMIT 2) b
 ON players.scoreChange=b.scoreChange
```

Comment: just perfect!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by simply following this query as well.

```
    SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT playerName,teamName, scoreChange,category
            FROM players ORDER BY scoreChange LIMIT 2
        ) AS t1
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT playerName,teamName, scoreChange,category
            FROM players ORDER BY scoreChange DESC LIMIT 2
        ) AS t2
```

Comment: to the point!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `UNION`, either with 2 derived tables as in Jilendra's answer (1st query) or simplified, without derived tables:

```
( SELECT playerName, teamName, scoreChange, category 
  FROM players  
  ORDER BY scoreChange DESC
  LIMIT 2
) 
UNION 
( SELECT playerName, teamName, scoreChange, category 
  FROM players 
  ORDER BY scoreChange
  LIMIT 2
) 
-- ORDER BY scoreChange DESC                -- optional
 ;
```

Comment: Very simple!!! Great!!!